# Ubuntu 16.04 - detect nvidia card type

Tags: command-line, nvidia

I have an Nvidia card, yet I am trying to find a one line script that would let me know what's the brand name of a card on ubuntu 16.04. I have done a few things to find out what video card type I have on this rig:

- hardinfo (GUI)
- glxinfo | grep OpenGL
- mesa-utils
- lspci -vnn | grep VGA (adding many attributes and options to this command)
- lshw -C video

The main response I got was: `VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1c82 (rev a1)` other than that, I did get alot of peripheral and valuable info, yet **none** of these options could tell me the brand type name of video card I have installed (i.e. GTX-770, GTX-1080, etc), unlike other OS's that detect this out of the box.

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps this would be helpful: `nvidia-smi --query-gpu=gpu_name --format=csv,noheader` ? If so I will make this a formal 'answer'...

Comment: nvidia-smi: command not found

Comment: I found the answer, yet god knows why no one created an app to solve this as an assoc array to give out a simple answer string.
The dictionary is here: http://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/387.12/README/supportedchips.html -  feel free to make this an answer buddy.

Comment: I think I see the issue with `nvidia-smi` which in Ubuntu is installed away from your $PATH. Can you give the results of this command: `sudo find /usr -iname nvidia-smi`  ? My suspicion is that the result will be: `/usr/lib/nvidia-340/bin/nvidia-smi`. If so the following should kick start the command:  `ln -sv /usr/lib/nvidia-340/bin/nvidia-smi /usr/bin` Then my neat `nvidia-smi` command may restore your faith in NVidia and Linux in general :)